# Use OnChange function for selectAll option

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is possible to use for a drop down list with multi select same function when the "select all" option is checked?

For example. I have:

```
 onChange: function f (element, checked) {...}
```

and I would like to use for

```
onSelectAll:  same_function_f()
```

Can this be used like that? I tried to use "trigger" option but no result.

Comment: Can you provide a snippet with what you tried and explain better what you expect?

Comment: i tried as this example:  $('#myDropdownList').trigger("onchange");